# Postgresql enabling extensions without super-user

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-extensions

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 server on which I have scripts that create roles and databases for users automatically. Within these databases it would be helpful to enable specific extensions (e.g. pgcrypto), but as I understand it one must be a superuser to run `CREATE EXTENSION`. Is there a way to enable such extensions without manually logging in with a superuser account?

Comment: Have you tried adding them to `template1` and then creating each user database from `template1` like `CREATE DATABASE foo OWNER=userfoo TEMPLATE=template1`?

Comment: @Kassandry no hadn't thought of that, but is a good thought. Ideally I'd like the owners to be able to add the extension if they wish, but this is still an acceptable possibility.

Comment: can you add extensions after database creation using this method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html) on Extensions,

> superuser (boolean) **If this parameter is true (which is the default), only superusers can create the extension** or update it to a new version. If it is set to false, just the privileges required to execute the commands in the installation or update script are required.

The value isn't set in [`pgcrypto.control`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/pgcrypto/pgcrypto.control), so it's defaulting to true which requires a SuperUser.

This means you can not `CREATE EXTENSION` as the mere owner of the database, despite what the docs on [CREATE EXTENSION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) lead you to believe.

I tried hard setting it to `false`, and no joy. C is an untrusted language and you'll get

> ERROR:  permission denied for language c

From [the docs on pg_language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-language.html)

> Only superusers can create functions in untrusted languages.

... of course you can make `c` trusted with `UPDATE pg_language set lanpltrusted = true where lanname = 'c';` as a superuser. Then `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto` will work fine as a non-superuser. But, that sounds like a bad idea if you have to worry about your users uploading source to your extension directory and then installing it in the database. That is to say, I wouldn't go that far. I'd find another way to skin this cat.

Comment: Thanks Evan, that's as thorough an answer as I could ask for. I'll probably opt for @Kassandry's cat-skinning proposal to get around this. I did also think about wrapping the CREATE EXTENSION in a stored procedure, but couldn't find a route to making this work in the same database without dblink authentication yuckiness.

Comment: What's the point, then, of not having any option in `pg_dump` to prevent it from dumping statements regarding extensions? I currently have to use external text processing tools to remove those statements from the SQL dumped by `pg_dump`.

Comment: @Evan Carroll:  is it possible to set the superuser to false via psql cli? I have an instance on amazon aws rds and don't have access to  pgcrypto.control .

Comment: @ribamar no because that would mean that anyone connected to the database could perform literal arbitrary code execution as the db postmaster. that would be a horrible idea.

Comment: not anybody, the superuser. I understand that this way you differentiate the operating system super from the dbms super user, although if I was making such a decision I would go for enpowering the tool, and if really needed to create yet another more powerful user, i'd implement it inside the tool.

Comment: I'm not sure of the question. The system-"super user" is totally irrelevant to the database, unless you're running it on a privileged port. The database itself has a notion of a "super user" which has all of the abilities of the system-user that is running database server daemon.